# Is "payment mode" acceptable

Tags: american-english

I'm checking an update before release and as I was checking everything out, I realized the English version of our product uses "Payment mode" as caption for payment methods. I wasn't exactly sure if it was an accepted term or not. I know mode of payment exists, but I've never heard of "payment mode".

Comment: If you're not limited to the number of symbols, why not use "Payment method"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Payment mode" would be fine. It would get the message across quite unambiguously. However, I think the more common phrase is "payment ***method***," just so you are aware. If I were in your position (I too am a software developer), I would probably not bother the project manager with this issue, since it would probably set you back to change it.

Comment: @Stephie No worries, I work in the IT department for a global corporate bank. The red tape is horrifying. If I have to talk to non-IT, a change like this could easily set back our release another iteration.